# How can Wakanda defend themselves?

Tags: marvel-cinematic-universe, black-panther

*Wakanda* is a closed country who does not let the world know they have highly advanced technology. In fact the world sees them as primarily a farming nation. We know they defend their borders, especially because when *T'Challa* goes off to try to capture *Klaue*, he tells *W'Kabi* to stay and defend the border.

How has *Wakanda* managed to defend it's borders for so long (e.g. against colonization by Europe and against attacks from neighboring countries) without letting others realize that their weapons (such as arm cannons and spaceships) are highly advanced? Wouldn't other countries be suspicious of a "farming nation" who nevertheless have one of the most advanced military forces in the world?

Comment: My impression (which is only an impression hence I am not answering) is that they mostly rely on hiding - looking like the country is just mountains.  The only "entrance" we've seen has been to fly at speed into a cliff.

Comment: There's no evidence for it necessarily but, _leave no witnesses_ could always be a possibility.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> How has Wakanda managed to defend its borders for so long (e.g. against colonization by Europe and against attacks from neighboring countries) without letting others realise that their weapons (such as arm cannons and spaceships) are highly advanced?

### Primarily, via deception

You are assuming that outsiders / neighboring countries have tried to invade Wakanda but there is little or no evidence of this.

Even so, there would have to be a *reason* for invasion and, as far as the rest of the world is concerned.... **there's nothing there worth having.**

That's assuming you could get an invading force there at all. As was stated in a news report

> ..it remains one of the poorest countries in the world...fortified by 
>   mountain ranges... and an impenetrable rainforest...

That doesn't sound like an inviting prospect to invade an apparently dirt-poor nation that's not bothering you.

---

> Wouldn't other countries be suspicious of a "farming nation" who nevertheless have one of the most advanced military forces in the world?

If they knew of the " most advanced military forces in the world" they might be...but they **don't**.

It's clear that **no-one** has any idea of the capabilities of Wakanda, not the UN, not SHIELD, not the CIA...*no-one*.

> With all due respect, King T'Challa...what can a nation of farmers have to offer the rest of the world?

Answer (score 2):

To piggyback on iandotkelly, I recall it's mentioned in the beginning that they disguised their civilization in a rainforest, so that no one knew about them.

According to the [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wakanda_(comics)#History):

> Knowing that others would attempt to manipulate and dominate Wakanda
>   for this rare and valuable resource, T'Chaka conceals his country from
>   the outside world. He sells off minute amounts of the valuable
>   vibranium while surreptitiously sending the country's best scholars to
>   study abroad, consequently turning Wakanda into one of the world's
>   most technologically advanced nations.